# Checking the size of a list of arrays

Tags: c#, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list of string arrays:

```
List<string[]> parsedRaw = new List<string[]>();
```

This list contains lines read in from a CSV, where parsedRaw[3][5] would be the fifth item read off the third line of the CSV.

I know that I can find the number of rows in the list with:

```
parsedRaw.Count
```

But, given a row, how can I find the number of elements in that row?  I'm trying to implement a test before entering a loop to read from the list, in order to avoid an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error, where the loop is:

```
for (k = 0; k < nBytes; k++)
{
    TheseBytes[k] = (byte)parsedRaw[i][StartInt + k];
}
```

I'm encountering the error on a row in the CSV that has fewer elements than the others.  Before entering this loop, I need to check whether parsedRaw[i] has at least "StartInt + nBytes" elements.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried using a lambda expression?

Comment: Actually parsedRaw[3][5] would be the 6th item from the 4th line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A row is just a string array `string[]`, so you can find its size using the `Length` property of the array.

```
foreach (string[] row in parsedRaw) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != row.Length ; i++) {
        // do something with row[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get a solution using the Length property by adding the following if statement as a prerequisite for entering the for loop: "if (parsedRaw[i].Length >= (StartInt + nBytes))"  Thanks for pointing out the Length property.

Answer (score 3):

The number of elements in a given row is determined by

```
parsedRaw[theRowIndex].Length
```

To fix your for loop you need to constrain the `StartInt + k` value to be less than the minimum of `nBytes` and the row length

```
for (k = 0; (k < nBytes) && (k + StartInt < parsedRaw[i].Length); k++)
{
    TheseBytes[k] = (byte)parsedRaw[i][StartInt + k];
}
```

Comment: This was a helpful suggestion, but it looks like you dropped nBytes out of it.  This loop would read all the way to the end of the row, but I only need to pull out nBytes worth of elements each time I encounter this loop.

Comment: @Patrigon my bad, added it back in

Comment: Actually, now I'm thinking that this is a nicer looking solution than nesting the for loop inside an if loop.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<string[]> parsedRaw = new List<string[]>();
parsedRaw.Add(new string[] {"test1", "test2"});
parsedRaw.Add(new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" });
int totalSize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < parsedRaw.Count(); i++)
{
    int rowSize = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < parsedRaw[i].Count(); k++)
    {
        rowSize += parsedRaw[i][k].Length;    
    }                
    totalSize += rowSize;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like parsedRaw[i].Count() returns the same value as parsedRaw[i].Length.  This could have also worked for me.